# Composition of Borel relations

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X,Y,Z$ be Polish spaces, or standard Borel spaces, and let us consider two relations $A \subseteq X \times Y$ and $B \subseteq Y \times Z$ that are Borel sets. Define their composition as
$$
  C := \{(x,z): \; \exists y \text{ such that }(x,y)\in A \text{ and } (y,z)\in B\}.
$$
Is $C$ a Borel subset of $X \times Z$? I can show that it is at least analytic.

Comment: Another meaningful notion of composition for relations (coming from Computable Analysis) consists in the following, in your notations: $C:=\{(x,z) : \forall y ((x,y)\in A \to \exists z' (y,z')\in B) \land \exists y ((x,y)\in A \land (y,z)\in B)\}$.

Comment: The idea is that the domain of $C$ consists in those $x$ in the domain of $A$ such that for every $y$, $(x,y)\in A$ implies $y$ is in the domain of $B$. Where the domain of the relation $A$ for example is $\{x\in X\mid \exists y (x,y)\in A\}$. This notion has proved better behaved in the context of Computable Analysis. For this notion the counterexample of @tapio-rajala does not (at least directly) work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X= \{0\}$, $Y = Z = [0,1]$ and $A = X \times Y$. Take $B \subset Y \times Z$ Borel such that its projection to $Z$, $S = \text{proj}_ZB$, is not Borel. Then
$C = \{0\}\times S$ is not Borel.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check other two answers if yours soon.